# .htaccess: Modding the URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I keep most of my website's public content in a folder named "pages", inside there I have a folder for each page, then inside each of those I have folders for each type of content.

**Edit:** Rewrote it to be more understandable.

So my typical URL is: `http://www.example.co.uk/folderName/folderName/folderName/fileName.php`

But I would like it to display like this: `http://www.example.co.uk/fileName`

I would also need to URL to be work with PHP variables stuck on the end of it, like so: `http://www.example.co.uk/fileName?phpVar=1`

I know it's possible, as I see it done everywhere. :L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^fileName1/?$ folderName/folderName/folderName/fileName1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^fileName2/?$ folderName/folderName/folderName/fileName2.php [L]
```

Should do what you're looking for. Assuming you want `http://example.com/about.php` to be seen as `http://example.com/about` by the users.

Adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` might be necessary, too, but it's not clear from your description.

---

To get your home page to always show "home" in the url, you'll want to use something like the following in your index file:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/index.php' or $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/') {
  header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/home');
}
```

And then add this to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Well, it want "http://example.com/folderName/folderName/folderName/fileName.php" to be seen as "http://example.com/fileName" if that makes sense?

Comment: Are all those "folderNames" the same? If there's not some sort of pattern to the folder names, this could be substantially more difficult.

Comment: No, unfortunately, they're not named the same. However, there is one pattern - there are always 3 folderNames before the fileName?

Comment: Is there no way that you could extract what's between .php and the preceding forward slash - /fileName.php to fileName? Then you could just erase the URL and stick that on the end.

Comment: That's not quite how URL rewriting works. Without any pattern, you'll either need to hardcode in each URL individually like `RewriteRule ^about/?$ folderName/folderName/folderName/about.php [L]`, or you could store the paths in a database and pass the access url as a parameter to your index.php, where it redirects to the proper page.

Comment: Hmm. Right now I don't know anything about databases but I only have around 5 or 6 .php files, so hardcoding would be fine for now. what would be the general syntax for changing `http://www.example.com/folderName/folderName/folderName/fileName.php` to `http://www.example.com/fileName`? Or is that what you wrote there?

Comment: What I wrote there should work. I'll update my answer so it's easier to read.

Comment: As a test, I have:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^aboutMe/?$ pages/aboutMe/pages/aboutMe.php [L]` (each on it's own line, of course)

and it's still not working. I've cleared my cache, ensured it has been uploaded and tried it on a different computer and everything. ¬¬ (sorry this is taking so long)

Comment: It's working fine on my server. Just to be sure, this should go in your root-level .htaccess file. Are you getting any sort of error message? If so, what? Also, could you pastebin your htaccess, removing any sensitive information, of course?

Comment: Yes, it is in the root-level. I've never moved it and `RewriteRule`s have worked before. I am unaware of any errors. Is there a way for me to check? Here's my .htaccess in it's entirety: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27573003/htaccess.txt

Comment: That's odd. It ought to work. Let me take a look at it when I'm fresh in the morning and see if anything stands out.

Comment: Yeah.. I've never had much luck with RewriteRules. Oki doke.

Comment: Just copy/pasted your rules onto my server and replicated the file structure and it works perfectly fine. You can see it here in action: [rewritten url](http://dambrisco.com/test/aboutMe) - [real source](http://dambrisco.com/test/pages/aboutMe/pages/aboutMe.php). The .htaccess it's using is [here](http://dambrisco.com/test/htaccess.php).

Comment: That's very strange, as "RewriteRule"s have definitely worked in the past and my index and error page redirection, etc is definitely working, so .htaccess IS in the right location.. yet it's not rewriting the URLs now..

I don't wish to inconvenience you more, but is there anything I could do to troubleshoot this? Should I contact my webhosters or..?

Comment: Contacting your webhost is probably the best thing to do at this point. I'd also suggest commenting out all your bot filters and testing without them, just in case. It's rather strange, and I wish I had a better answer for you.

Comment: Oh.. I feel kind of stupid now.. It wasn't displaying "correctly" as it never occurred to me that I would have to change the `href`s in my navigation bar, so the URL was displaying what the `href`s contained. I just assumed that the URL would be rewritten as soon as it was loaded, regardless of anything else. It's working now. But as a last request, how would I add `/home` when I'm on my home page? :)

So sorry for how much I've put you out due to my stupidity. :(

Comment: I feel that I should clarify that I wish it to display `http://www.example.com/home` when `http://www.example.com` is entered.. If you know what I mean?

Comment: No worries at all! I know how frustrating this stuff can be. To get it to display `/home` on when just the domain is entered, you'll have to use some PHP. I'll modify my answer to show this since comments aren't well suited to it.

Comment: It all worked except for  the .htaccess entry - I had to change it to `RewriteRule ^home/?$ /pages/index/pages/index.php [L]` and then it worked. Thank you so much. I appreciate it! And thank you for being so patient. YAY! :D

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this?

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Rewrite /filename to /pages/filename/pages/filename.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /pages/$1/pages/$1.php [L]
```

Comment: It has definitely been updated on the webserver for at least 5 minutes and I cleared my browser cache but it seems to have had absolutely no effect on my URL.. :S mod_rewrite has worked many times in the past (and an hour ago, actually), so I don't think it's a configuration issue..

Comment: Wait.. your comment says "Rewrite /filename to /pages/filename/pages/filename.php". It's the opposite I want to do! :L